# SQL query using ISNULL

Tags: c#, sql-server

I'm writing the following SQL query using the TableAdapter Query Configuration Wizard in Visual Studio.

```
SELECT  COUNT(*) AS census
FROM Inventory INNER JOIN Taxonomy ON Inventory.GlobalID = Taxonomy.GlobalID
WHERE (Inventory.Institution = @institution) AND (Inventory.Year = @year) AND 
  (Inventory.Nending > 0)
```

I'm trying to add the following criteria to the WHERE clause:

```
(Taxonomy.Class = ISNULL(@class, Taxonomy.Class))
```

so that either
 1) only rows that match the @class input parameter are returned or
 2) all rows are returned regardless of their TaxonomyGlobal.Class value.

When I add this statement to the query my C# code that calls the query throws a System.ArgumentNullException error and states the @class value cannot be null.

Any help on how to add this criterion to the WHERE clause would be appreciated.

C# code:

```
namespace CollectionMetrics
{
  class DatabaseQueries
  {
      QueryDataSetTableAdapters.InventoryTableAdapter queryAdapter = 
            new QueryDataSetTableAdapters.InventoryTableAdapter();

      public void CensusQuery(string institution, short year, string xclass)
      {
            int census = 0;
            string localClass = xclass;
            if (xclass == "All Classes") localClass = null;

            census = (int)queryAdapter.CensusBySpecies(localClass, institution, year);
            censusOutput.Add(census);
      }
  }
}
```

Comment: ISNULL doesn't tell you whether an expressin is null or not, but simply replaces an null values with a specified value.

Comment: @DavidP, I think he gets that.   Look closely once again at how ISNULL is being used here.

Comment: Please provide your complete C# code related to this question, that will help us better to understand you

Answer (score 2, accepted):

SQL:

```
(@class IS NULL OR Taxonomy.Class = @class)
```

Since you are using `TableAdapter`, you will need to edit the field to allow nulls:

https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms233762.aspx

Setting the AllowDbNull Property

> To enable a query to accept null values In the Dataset Designer,
>   select the TableAdapter query that needs to accept null parameter
>   values. Select Parameters in the Properties window and click the
>   ellipsis (…) button to open the Parameters Collection Editor. Select
>   the parameter that allows null values and set the AllowDbNull property
>   to true.

If you are using `SqlParameters`:

C#

```
 var param = new SqlParameter("@class", (object) classVariable ?? DBNull.Value);
```

Replace `classVariable` with the name of the variable you are using in your code to set the value for the `@class` `SqlParameter`. The cast to `object` is required because the variable does not have the same type as `DBNull`.

Comment: Did you use the code in my edit where you are passing `DbNull.Value` if the original variable is null?

Comment: You will have to replace `classVariable` with whatever variable you are using to set the value for the `@class` parameter. For `DBNull`, sorry, capitalize the `B`

Comment: See my updated answer. You have to add the cast to `object` in there, then it should work. https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms173224.aspx

Comment: Can you edit the code for `CensusBySpecies`? Whichever method finally builds the query should be the one handling the possible `NULL` value, which is where the code I provided should be (or updated code if yours is not using `SqlQueryParameters`.

Comment: I can edit the code for CensusBySpecies, but its just the SQL query within the TableAdapter.  Visual Studio won't let me put anything else in there.

Comment: Ok, if that is coming from the `TableAdapter`, then you need to set the `@class` field to enable nulls. I updated the answer again. With this set, you should just be able to pass `null` for the `localClass` value.

Comment: Using the SQL statement above and setting the AllowDbNull Property to true is the answer!  Thank you so much!

Answer (score 0):

I once tried doing what you're trying to do, thinking this was a nifty way to ignore parameters that weren't passed from the front end (and therefore were NULL).

But then I learned that using `ISNULL()` in the `WHERE` clause like this prevents indexes from being used, making your query much SLOWER than if you used:

```
WHERE (Taxonomy.Class = @Class OR @Class IS NULL)
```

Unintuitive, I admit; the way you're trying looks like it would be cleaner and therefore faster, but for SQL performance, the most important thing is using available indexes, and so it turns out the `A OR B` approach is actually faster than the `ISNULL()` approach you want to use.

As to why you're getting an error, it's got to be something the wizard is enforcing.   If you tried your query purely in SQL (using SSMS), it would allow it.  UNLESS your query is actually in a stored procedure and `@Class` is a required parameter.